# Service won't automatically start after reboot

Tags: c#, .net, windows-vista

I wrote a windows service (`Win32 API`) that uses a `.NET` assembly written in `C#`.

The service is set up to start automatically. In `Windows XP` all works well but under Vista the service is not automatically started (after reboot) because the `.NET` component is throwing an exception. But if I start the service manually, it works well.

It seems to be a security problem. The service is running under the local system account.

Comment: What exception is the code throwing?

Comment: Try running it as a non-service for debugging. (xclass.runConsole(Nothing) instead of ServiceBase.Run(New xclass), or try logging errors in a try/catch.

Comment: what was your MS Vista event viewer showing the exception ?